# Copy file names / file paths to clipboard in Krusader like in Total Commander

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, filemanager, krusader

How to configure file manager `Krusader` to copy names or full paths for selected files / directories like in `Total Commander`?

Related question: [Shortcut to select / copy current directory in Krusader file manager](https://askubuntu.com/q/1438448/1548713)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Krusader` -> `Useractions` -> `Manage User Actions...`

Add two new user actions with the following configuration:

```
Identifier: Copy Names
Title: &Copy Names
Command: %_Clipboard("%aList("Selected", "\n", "Yes", "", "No")%")%
Shortcut: Ctrl + Alt + N

Identifier: Copy Paths
Title: &Copy Paths
Command: %_Clipboard("%aList("Selected", "\n", "", "", "No")%")%
Shortcut: Ctrl + Alt + P
```

`Krusader` -> `Settings` -> `Configure Keyboard Shortcuts...`

```
Remove duplicated Ctrl + Alt + P shortcut from 'Play/Pause Job' action
or user other shortcut.
```

To check config select several files/directories. Press `Ctrl + Alt + N` to copy to clipboard names, `Ctrl + Alt + P` to copy paths.

Description for commands config from [Krusader UserActions](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/krusader/krusader/useractions.html):

```
List - replaced by a list of all <first parameter>
    Parameter: Which items; either “All”, “Selected”, “Files” or “Dirs”
    Parameter (optional): Separator between the items. Default: “ ”
    Parameter (optional): Omit the current path. Default: no
    Parameter (optional): Filtermask (for all but “Selected”).
                          Default: *
    Parameter (optional): Automatic escape spaces. Default: yes
Select - manipulates the selection in a panel
    Parameter: Filtermask
    Parameter (optional): manipulate in which way; either “Set”,
                          “Add” or “Remove”. Default: “Set”
Clipboard - manipulates the clipboard
    Parameter: The text that should go to the clipboard 
               (you may want to use “%aCurrent%” here)
    Parameter (optional): Append the text to the current content
                          of the clipboard with this separator
```

Related links:

- [Re: 'krusader-users' Copy full path of file](https://www.mail-archive.com/krusader-users@googlegroups.com/msg01109.html)
- [Copy full path of file](https://groups.google.com/g/krusader-users/c/BVYwyuWH0k4/m/r_1BIl__AgAJ)
- [Make 'copy names to clipboard' more versatile and more prominent (like in Total Commander)](https://groups.google.com/g/krusader-users/c/Td1EjzyN7EQ)
- [Krusader UserActions](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/krusader/krusader/useractions.html)
- [Krusader Useractions Menu](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/krusader/krusader/useractions-menu.html)
- [Copy file path or file name to clipboard (Total Commander)](https://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=17833)
- [Copy current path to clipboard or select address bar in Total Commander](https://superuser.com/questions/387833/copy-current-path-to-clipboard-or-select-address-bar-in-total-commander)
- [Total Commander for Linux](https://www.ghisler.ch/wiki/index.php/Total_Commander_for_Linux)