# Shortcut to select / copy current directory in Krusader file manager

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, filemanager, krusader

How to select and copy current working directory in `Krusader` file manager without using mouse?

Related question: [Copy file names / file paths to clipboard in Krusader like in Total Commander](https://askubuntu.com/q/1434480/1548713)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in `Nautilus` shortcut `Ctrl + L` selects current directory. `Ctrl + C` to copy it.

The corresponding action called `Go to Location Bar`. It can be added to toolbar by means of `Settings -> Configure Toolbars...` menu.
Shortcut can be changed by means of `Settings -> Configure Keyboard Shortcuts... -> Go to Location Bar` menu.

It will be useful to have single shortcut for selecting and copying the current path at once. But by now I do not know how to configure it.